# How to import data via Spark connection into R environment from cluster?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, sparkr, r-server

I followed this link to make a connection with Spark and my R server.

[Connection b/w R studio server pro and hive on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325464/connection-b-w-r-studio-server-pro-and-hive-on-gcp)

I can see my dataframe but cannot call it into R environment to run analysis on. Can anyone please suggest me the correct way ?

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sparklyr::spark_install()
#config
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/lib/spark")
config <- spark_config()
#connect
sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn-client",config = config,version="2.2.1")
```

I can see my table "rdt" , but when I call it says object not found.

[image: rdt table]

this is what i tried :

```
  data <- rdt
```

that gives error like so : Error: object 'rdt' not found

then the only way was to put the file directly into the cluster and set working directory to call it (beats the purpose then .. ) I want to call it, how we would usually import a df, in this case from sparklyr connection

```
    setwd("~/Directory")
    data2 <- read.csv("rdt.csv",header = TRUE)
    str(data2)
```

Comment: Could you include code you use to "call it" and the exception?

Comment: I have made the edits to the question ^ @user8371915